# Modified column's value

Tags: 2007, column

I experienced that when I make some changes in a document without checking out the document, the value in **Modified** column won't change/update, this value changes/gets updated **only** when i check the document out, make changes and then check in the document! Is it how SharePoint normally act?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, if the doc library requires check-in/out then any changes you make are private (except to admins of course) until you check them in. All the metadata inc modified date will be public information so it fits that this is hidden until you are ready to check it in.

Comment: So from your comment i understand that if the library settings doesn't require In/Outchecking, the value in Modified column wont get updated after changing any document?

Comment: If you remove the requirement for check-in/out, then each time the document is changed, it is public (in the sense of allowed permissions) and the meta data is reflected immediately. So you'll see the modified date change at each document revision.

Comment: And that's exactly what doesn't happen! I have removed the requirement but the Modified column still doesn't get updated!!

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying a document without checking it out so you’ve set the library to not require check out for editing document.

In your case every edit without checking out the document should update Modified field and that should be visible to everyone with read rights.

Every edit on a checked out document will update Modified field but will be visible only to you. When you check in the document every reader can see the new Modified value.

That’s for out of the box document library. In a custom solution SystemUpdate() can be called to update the database without changing Modified date.

If your library is part of a custom solution then try with another out-of-the-box document library.